# Where i put my index.php when using docker nginx image

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I can't find where i put my file index.php so that ngnix can interpreter my file.
All containers are working and when i put `localhost:8080` nginx works
Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  image: nginx
  volumes:
   - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  environment:
   - NGINX_HOST=foobar.com
   - NGINX_PORT=8080

php:
       image: php:7.0-fpm
       expose:
           - 9000
       volumes_from:
           - app
       links:
           - elastic

app:
       image: php:7.0-fpm
       volumes:
           - .:/src

elastic:
       image: elasticsearch:2.3
       volumes:
         - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
         - ./elasticsearch/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs
       expose:
         - "9200"
       ports:
         - "9200:9200"
```

Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount same volumes for both PHP and Nginx docker image.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./nginx-config/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    image: php:7.3-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
     - ./app:/app
```

in the above compose file, code is placed under `app` folder in the host.

Tree

```
├── app
│   ├── helloworld.php
│   └── index.php
├── docker-compose.yml
└── nginx-config
    └── default.conf
```

You Nginx config should use docker service network to connect with php-fpm container.

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name php-docker.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /app/;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Or you can try the working example from Github.

```
git clone https://github.com/Adiii717/dockerize-nginx-php.git
cd dockerize-nginx-php;
docker-compose up
```

Now open the browser

http://localhost/helloworld.php

Comment: Thanks for your responce. Well, i cloned the project from github then i installed ElasticSearch with composer.json -> Vendor is generated but when i try to do "require '../vendor/autoload.php';" i got an error say that i cannot find this file "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/index.php line 4"

Comment: BTW first better to check helloworld if that's working then issue is different?

Comment: Helloworld and index.php are working perfectly. The probleme occure when i put "require" even i put a file under /app

Comment: seems like require is not valid `require '../vendor/autoload.php` , where is vendor folder ?

Comment: for the first time, i installed the vendor under the parent folder of /app. i puted like you said. Then i installed composer.json under /app then i changed as `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` It's usually the same problem `Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /app/test.php on line 5`

Comment: Thanks Adiii, problem solved. i was wrong, i used `require  '/vendor/autoload.php'` in the place of `require  'vendor/autoload.php'`.